# C# use cookie httprequest to webclient

Tags: c#, cookies, httprequest, webclient

I logged site by httprequest and cookie in varible cookiecontanse . But now i need to set cookie got for webclient . I used line

```
 webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,cookiecontanse.ToString)
```

But not work. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Usage :

```
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        cookieJar.Add(new Cookie("my_cookie", "cookie_value", "/", "mysite"));

        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);

        string response = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/response_with_cookie_only.php");
```

---

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        if (setCookieHeader != null)
        {
            //do something if needed to parse out the cookie.
            if (setCookieHeader != null)
            {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
                this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

You will see two overridden methods for GetWebRequest and GetWebResponse. These methods can be overridden to handle the cookie container.